# Encrpyt/Decrypt Password in Android Application

Tags: android

What is the best way / method that can be used to encrpyt password in an Android application?

My program requires user to register. So do I encrpyt the password in my Android and POST it to PHP to store or should I POST it to PHP then encrpyt at the server side?

Plus, my program allows user to retrieve their password. How do I handle them?

Comment: It's generally considered bad practise to allow passwords to be retrieved, even if they are stored in encrypted form. If a user forgets their password, you should reset it to a random value and force them to change it.

Comment: Just curious, what's the name of your app?

Comment: good point adelphus, I might look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
my program allows user to retrieve their password
```

Thus the password *retrieved* at Android through network communication **must** be encrypted and not plaintext, to be decrypted at android. Thus while saving, encypting the password again at android before sending out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you setup an SSL (128 or 256) connection to your server.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php
This website has good information to get you started.

It also depends on what the purpose of the storage is. You can encrypt it on the android side (using AES, or similar encryption algorithms... see [This Tutorial](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings)).

It might make more sense to use a hash algorithm to improve network and device latency (in this case check out MD5, or SHA-1 hashing... it's extremely straight-forward).

If you can give more information on what you're trying to accomplish it will be much easier to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should never encrypt passwords! **EVER**.

You should hash and salt passwords. A user should never ever be able to retrieve a plaintext password! Not trying to self-promote, but for an explanation on how to store passwords properly using hash + salt, I wrote a blog entry about it [here](http://thecodemechanic.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/introduction-to-strong-cryptography-p1-0-hash-functions-us-patriots/).